# Is there any Image Uploader for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, upload

Is there any free image uploader control for ASP.NET MVC?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery/JavaScript file upload scripts. First found:

http://www.uploadify.com/
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

What do you mean by image uploader control? What are your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

In this article , Stephen have showed the good example of using silver light upload control for multiple uploading with progress bar in an aspnet MVC application, worth a look:
[Upload control in aspnet mvc](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/10/03/asp-net-mvc-application-building-family-video-website-5-multiple-file-upload-with-progress.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload"/>
```

Or did you want something more?